# SparkThriftServer - heap memory not being freed

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, thrift

`start-thriftserver.sh` is started and then sparksql queries are run, client sessions connecting to the thriftserver port are closed, but even after no queries are run for hours the heap memory consumed is still high. What needs to be done to ensure the heap memory is freed?

`spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect` is set to true already in `spark-defaults.conf`

Comment: If you're actively creating databases and tables, those won't be freed until dropped

Comment: sparkthrift is just pointing at hive tables. No tables are being cached in spark. When I start sparkthrift the memory used is very low but after select queries are run the memory used goes very high (100s of GBs) and stays high even when no more select queries are run

Comment: I would guess it caches tables for future queries